# How to easily extract the 2nd last element in an array/string in Azure Data Factory Expression?

Tags: split, expression, azure-data-factory

Let's say string is a variable file name like few examples below:

1. file1_name_cr_001.csv
2. file2_name1_name2.nn.123.456_updt_000.csv
3. filename_2012.444.1234_utc_del_004.csv

The length of last 8 string values will always remain fixed i.e. (_001.csv,_000.csv,_004.csv). We need to only extract values = **cr, updt, del**

However, neither split() nor substring() in ADF allows negative index values and throws error :- array index is outside bounds , otherwise this split() could have been the simplest method i.e `@split(variables('var1'),'_')[-2]`

Here's similar thread:- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/46070

Please suggest a simplest method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this method for above scenario to be working and simpler since I just needed to find the correct element position...therefore, first got the entire length and substracted the required array element/string position - passed to split():

```
@split(variables('var1'),'_')[sub(length(split(variables('var1'),'_')),2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We might be able to use a reverse trick here:

```sql
SELECT
    filename,
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(
        REVERSE(filename),
        CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(filename)) + 1,
        CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(filename), CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(filename)) + 1) -
            CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(filename)) - 1)) AS path
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that the above will likely not perform well at all.  If you need to quickly access the various path components, then consider storing them separately when you insert the entire path.

Comment: Thanks, but am specifically looking for an expression in Azure Data Factory (ADF v2)